# Advanced Searching Using Externally-Hosted Elasticsearch Instance

Tags: elasticsearch, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am trying to enable search with Elasticsearch enabled for my self-hosted Gitlab instance.

My question is this:

I have an Elasticsearch instance that is external to my Gitlab instance i.e. my Gitlab instance is hosted on one server and my Elasticsearch instance is hosted on another server.

Am I able to use the external Elasticsearch instance to provide the Elasticsearch functionality that Gitlab requires in order to enable Advanced Search functionality?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have network connectivity between your gitlab instance and your Elasticsearch  instance, you can use the Elasticsearch functionality.

Elasticsearch provides all the features and API in form of REST request and designed for distributed systems where several component of an application are hosted separately.

Note: you can just use the curl command curl :9200 from your gitlab  instance to see if you have network connectivity and if not, using security setting you can enable them , like in AWS ports settings can be changed using the security group.

Answer (score 0):

Note: [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#advanced-search-is-compatible-with-elasticsearch-8) (May 2022) offers new options.

> ### Advanced Search is compatible with Elasticsearch 8
>
> Elasticsearch 8 is the current version of Elasticsearch by Elastic. Previously, you could not use Elasticsearch 8 for Advanced Search. You had to use older versions instead. Starting in 15.0, you can use Elasticsearch 8 for Advanced Search.
>
> - If you use Elasticsearch 7.x, you must upgrade to GitLab 15.0 before upgrading to Elasticsearch 8.
> - If you use Elasticsearch 6.8, upgrade to any Elasticsearch 7.x version before upgrading to GitLab 15.0.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/elasticsearch.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7778).

---

And even, still with [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#advanced-search-is-compatible-with-opensearch) (May 2022)

> ### Advanced Search is compatible with OpenSearch
>
> [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org) is an open source Elasticsearch fork. Prior to GitLab 15.0, Advanced Search was not compatible with OpenSearch. If you used AWS-managed services, you had to use older versions of Elasticsearch.
> You can now take full advantage of OpenSearch for Advanced Search.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_0/gitlab_advanced_search_is_now_compatible_with_opensearch.png -- Advanced Search is compatible with OpenSearch]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/elasticsearch.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7777).